# Get current date object with passed time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have time slots as `10:00:00, 12:00:00` etc.

I want to get current moment date object with these times.

I am trying this way.

```
console.log(moment('10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:ss:mm').toDate())
```

But it logs `Invalid Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the shortest way

```js
// If you want set in your local
const localDate = moment('10:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss').toDate();
console.log('Local:', localDate);

// If you want set like utc
const utcDate = moment.utc('10:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss').toDate();
console.log('UTC:', utcDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
var date1 = moment().set({ "hour": 10, "minute": 32 });
console.log(date1.toDate());
```

---

```
const date = "2017-03-13";
const time = "18:00";
const timeAndDate = moment(date + ' ' + time);
console.log(timeAndDate.toDate());
```

---

```
moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ' + time).toDate()
```

Comment: I have time as string. Do I need to do `const [hour, minute] = '10:00:00'.split(':')`?

Comment: Please check updated answer and as per your requirement you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as below. I thought there would some method in the library to do it just in one line.

```
const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const time = '10:00:00';
console.log(moment(`${today} ${time}`).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```